# SQL Server to Teradata migration

Tags: sql-server, teradata, database-migration

We are migrating from SQL Server to Teradata database. All the views and tables are migrated. But the issue is that we aren't able to take the comments from each table.

In SQL Server we have a function called extended property which if used will get the comments from the respective tables/views. Badhri helped with providing a query for fetching the comment in Teradata in the same way but it doesn’t work in the expected way.

I tried inserting sample comments in columns and the below query is not fetching exact results. Can you please help?

Sample Query:

```
COMMENT ON COLUMN UtilityApp_DB.SQL_Views_Columns.ColumnNAME 'A Columnname for SQL Server!';

select  'COMMENT ON COLUMN '||trim(b.databasename)||'.'||trim(b.tablename) ||'.'||trim(b.columnname)||' IS '||''''||trim(b.commentstring)||''';'                                   
                   FROM DBC.Columns b
     WHERE b.CommentString IS NOT NULL
      AND DatabaseName='UtilityApp_DB'
     AND TableName in ('UtilityApp_DB.SQL_Views_Columns');
```

I created a table and tried inserting the values for the comment string in the table by copying the DBC Columns structure but still I can't get the comment string.

```
insert into UtilityApp_DB.commentstable (commentstring) values ('UtilityApp_DB.SQL_Views_Columns');
```

Answer (score 0):

`TableName` in `DBC.Columns` does not include the database name and `IS` in your string concatenation should be `AS`.

```
SELECT 'COMMENT ON COLUMN '||trim(b.databasename)||'.'||trim(b.tablename) ||'.'||trim(b.columnname)||' AS '||''''||trim(b.commentstring)||''';'
  FROM DBC.Columns
 WHERE DatabaseName = 'UtilityApp_DB'
   AND TableName IN ('SQL_Views_Columns');
```